# C++ "Unresolved External Symbol" error when using static LPWSTR

Tags: c++

Have just started with some Windows programming, and i´m working on a window class. I thougth that it was a good idea to have a static LPWSTR that I could use when I create different windows in my program. Doubt that I will need more when I move on to direct3D but I still want to have the feature, and it seems like it can be good to learn how Windows deals with a program that has multiple windows.

Know I dont really know how Windows uses the WINDCLASS(EX) classname, if there are any advantadges of having more than one class, in that case please tell me.

Well lets talk about my problem. I declare the static LPWSTR (Correct me if i´m wrong but this is a wchar_t*??) here:

```
class Window
{ 
public:
//other code removed
static LPWSTR windowClassName;
}
```

Then a set the variable before I create my first window:

```
Window::windowClassName = L"WindowClass";
Window window1 = Window(L"Engine Window1");
window1.initialize(hInstance, 100, 100, 1280, 720);
window1.showWindow(cmdShow);
```

But I get the unresolved externals error. This doesn´t make sense to me, so I can create a static variable in a class, make it public, but I can´t change it? What do I have to do to make this to work? Or is it just so simple that static members cant be set in a method? That I think would be really stuip since I can´t set it´s value during run-time. Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: It's just a symbol -- you need to create the variable in your cpp file like so: `LPWSTR Window::windowClassName;`

Comment: I solved it, quess it´s time to go to bed when you realize that your this stupid...

Comment: It seems like a bad idea to have a `static` here. What should happen if another class inherits from `Window`? Maybe you actually want a virtual function that returns the class name?